# syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO, expecting ',' or ';' in /Secured_Page_Edit.php on line 110

Tags: php, mysql, css

```
<?php

session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
header('Location: LoginForm.php');
}

?>

<html>


<head>

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Secured Page</title>

<style>
.db-table {position:absolute;top:95px;left:300px;}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<p align="left" style="margin-left:0px; margin-top:135px;">          
<form action="Secured_Page_Search.php" method="post">
Select_Table_To_Display:<br><select name="Table">
<option value="members">Members</option>
<option value="online">Online</option>
<input type="submit" name="submit_name" />

            </form>

<title>Secured Page</title>
<style type="text/css">
body{font-family:Impact;}                                    
#container{width:10000px;margin:auto;font-size:15pt;}

#menu{position:absolute;margin-top:10px;}
#menu ul .item{display:none;}
#menu ul:hover .item{display:block;background:#white;padding:1px;margin:1px;}

#menu ul:hover .item a{color:#abc;text-decoration:none;}
#menu ul:hover .item a:hover{color:grey;}

#menu ul{width:110px;float:left;margin:0px;padding:2px;background:white;list-

Style:none;}
.clear{clear:both;height:10px;}
</style>


<div id="container">
<h1></h1>

<div id="menu">

<p align="left" style="margin-left:0px; margin-top: 0px;">
<br><FONT FACE="arial">Logged In @: (<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>)</FONT></p>
</p>

<ul id="item1">
<li class="top">Profile</li>
<li class="item"><a href="#">Profile User</a></li>
<li class="item"><a href="#">Profile I.M.</li>
<li class="item"><a href="#">Profile O.P.</a></li>
</ul>

<ul id="item1">
<li class="top">Edit</li>
<li class="item"><a href="#">Edit User</a></li>
<li class="item"><a href="#">Edit I.M.</li>
<li class="item"><a href="#">Edit O.P.</a></li>
</ul>

</div>
<div class="clear"></div>

</body>


<br><FONT FACE="arial">


<?php

$Table = 'members';

$mysqli = new mysqli("XXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXXXX");
$result = $mysqli->query("SHOW TABLES");
while ( $row = $result->fetch_row() ){
$table = $row[0]; 
$result1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM $Table ORDER BY dt DESC LIMIT 0,12");
if($result1) {
echo '<table cellpadding="15" cellspacing="20" class="db-table">';
$column = $mysqli->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $Table");echo '<tr>';
while($row3 = $column->fetch_row() ) {
echo '<th>'.$row3[0].'</th>';
}
echo '</tr>';
while($row2 = $result1->fetch_row() ) {
echo '<tr>';
foreach($row2 as $key=>$value) {
LINE 110 ----> echo '<td style="padding-top:0px;padding-bottom:0px;">',$value,'
<a href="edit.php?id=<?' echo $row['id']; '?>">'Edit'</a></td>;'<------Line 110
  }
  echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table><br />';
}
}
$mysqli->close();

?>

<FONT FACE="impact">

<p align="left" style="margin-left:100px; margin-top:100PX;"> 

<form action="Secured_Page_Search_Email.php" method="post">
Search, Email:<br>                             <input type="text" name="email"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit_name" />
            </form>  

<p align="left" style="margin-left:100px; margin-top:10px;">    


<form action="Secured_Page_Search_User.php" method="post">
Search, User:<br>                       <input type="text" name="usr"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit_name" />
            </form>              

</FONT></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically i need the mysql table to print with a edit link... Seems so easy, but have been battling with this issue the last few hours. Line that has an issue:

Basically i need the mysql table to print with a edit link... Seems so easy, but have been battling with this issue the last few hours. Line that has an issue:

```
LINE 110 ----> echo '<td style="padding-top:0px;padding-bottom:0px;">',$value,'
<a href="edit.php?id=<?' echo $row['id']; '?>">'Edit'</a></td>;'<------Line 110
```

UPDATED CODE UPDATED CODE

```
echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'Edit'</a></td>;'
```

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO, expecting ',' or ';' in Secured_Page_Edit.php on line 113

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo '<td style="padding-top:0px;padding-bottom:0px;">'.$value.'
<a href="edit.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Edit</a></td>';
```

Answer (score 2):

The way you concatenate text and variables is wrong. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

You should write something like this:

```
LINE 110 ----> echo '<td style="padding-top:0px;padding-bottom:0px;">' . $value . '
<a href="edit.php?id='. $row['id'] .'">Edit</a></td>;'<------Line 110
```

More precisely, mixing dots and comma is fine, but if you use single quotes with echo, you should make sure to put either a dot or a comma right after them (if you want to continue your string [1]) or a semicolon if you're done [2].

```
echo 'Text and '.$variable; // [1]
echo $variable.' and text'; // [2]
```

See also http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php.

Answer (score 1):

Your php open/close tags are part of what is being echoed. As well as using commas rather then dots (.) to append the `$value`. However there is no reason to echo into the html string when already building the string in php.

```
echo '<td style="padding-top:0px;padding-bottom:0px;">',$value,'<a href="edit.php?id=<?' echo $row['id']; '?>">'Edit'</a></td>;'
```

I think you want:

```
echo '<td style="padding-top:0px;padding-bottom:0px;">'.$value.'<a href="edit.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Edit</a></td>;'
// Changes are:                                       ^         ^              ^                    ^
```

UPDATE (Thanks Fred) You can in fact use commas to append a string in an echo call. So this would also be valid:

```
echo '<td style="padding-top:0px;padding-bottom:0px;">', $value, '<a href="edit.php?id=', $row['id'], '">Edit</a></td>;'
```

Comment: Commas are fine in echo: echo takes an arbitrary number of arguments, and concatenates them all.  `echo 'a','b';` and `echo 'a'.'b';` produce the same output.

Comment: Wow never knew that. Seems like a perlism to me. I would expect to have to wrap it in parantheses if you were going to supply more that one argument. Learn something new everyday. Thanks for the tip